# An equality between probabilities in random walks study

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ is a set of independent random variables following the same law, at values in $\mathbb{Z^d}$. What is the fastest way to prove that, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\mathbb{P}(\forall i>0,X_1+X_2+...+X_i=0)=\mathbb{P}(\forall i>0,X_{k+1}+X_{k+2}+...+X_{k+i}=0) \;\;\;\;?$$

I am studying random walks on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ in the Garet-Kurtzmann's book, which uses this result but doesn't explain this and I can't find an easy explanation. Thank you all for your help !

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I can't see what would be your stopping time for Wald's formula here ?

Comment: The idea is that, for every nonnegative $k$, the distributions of the processes $(X_i)_{i\geqslant1}$ and $(X_{k+i})_{i\geqslant1}$ are the same hence $$E(F((X_i)_{i\geqslant1}))=E(F((X_{k+i})_{i\geqslant1}))$$ for every nonnegative functional $F$, say $$F((x_i)_{i\geqslant 1})=\mathbf 1_{\forall i,\,x_1+\cdots+x_i=0}.$$ A strange thing, however, is that with this functional $F$, both sides are zero unless the common distribution of the random variables $X_i$ is a Dirac mass at zero, so it might be useful to check the statement (anyway the reasoning to show the identity is the one above).

Comment: @Did Yes I agree. I was thinking there might be an easier way, because it is a part of a proof for a first semester of probability theory. If I am asked to detailing this, I will just give this idea. I have found an article which involved canonical space, but the level here is too high too. Thank you for answering !